# Play mp4 sequence file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to play a MP4 file sequence  with ffmpeg or ffplay.
Is it possible without first make a rendering?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Create a series of `ffplay` commands in a text file e.g. `ffplay file1`, then `ffplay file2`, then `ffplay file3`, etc. and run the text file as either a batch file (Windows) or shell script (*nix). Note that the exact contents of these files may vary slightly, depending on how your computer is setup up (OS and system path settings).